# Play chrome extension in background

Tags: google-chrome, background, google-chrome-extension

I am making an alert chrome extension, I want to make notification before appointment with specific time, I don't want user to keep the window of extesnion open all the time, I read about background from [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/background.html#use) .

I add background_page and background permission in manifest.json like this

```
 {
    "name": "Alert extention",
    "version": "2.0",
    "description": "Personal alert.",
    "background_page": "Alert.html",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "img/clock.png",
    "popup": "Alert.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "notifications","background"
    ]
}
```

But no notification occurs while extension is closed. I make reload for the extension the first notification occur but others don't.

[What should make ??? any suggestion??](http://code.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/background.html#use)

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem through wrapping the code I want to work in background into these two line of code.

```
chrome.extension.getViews().forEach(function(view){
      //my code go here!
});
```